# i can't place an order due to this error in one step checkout

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, payment-methods, paypal, braintree

I can't place an order due to this error in one step checkout so please check the console error about the Paypal response

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have the issue at the order submit URL `payment-information` , in order to debug the error check Magento `var/log` and `var/report` folder.

You have to debug the error at `Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement::savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder`.

And here

```
catch (\Exception $e) {
        throw new CouldNotSaveException(
            __('An error occurred on the server. Please try to place the order again.'),
            $e
        )
```

Change to

```
catch (\Exception $e) {
        throw new CouldNotSaveException(
            __($e->getMessage()),
            $e
        )
```

Then on network tab at the browser, you can your original error message.

You can use Max pronko module for getting the error.

https://www.maxpronko.com/how-to-show-payment-errors-on-the-checkout-payment-page-in-magento-2/